# slapd not launching on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, ldap

I have a slight problem with the openldap server installed with Mac OS X 10.6.8 (regular, not server). When I launch `slapd` in a terminal, it stops itself after 1 or 2 seconds... I just have the time to see its process... It doesn't seem to crash, because when I specify a log file in the configuration, the log is created, but empty.

However, when I launch it with the debug option, for example `-d 1`,it doesn't fork and stays in the terminal (that's the documented behavior) and it runs normally. I can connect, and so on... Meaning, I presume, that's not a config problem.

Is there something stupid I've forgotten? (btw, I've repaired the authorizations, just in case, but that doesn't change the problem...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error messages are logged to /private/var/log/slapd.log when the failed launch is attempted?

Comment: The log is empty...

Comment: Wow - I'd be interested in whether fs_events running when you launched the built in slapd shows what  is going on, but if you're happy with the BYO slapd, perhaps someone else can troubleshoot the built in one. Very odd but glad you have a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

The only workaround I found is to use macports to build the latest version of `slapd`, that works just fine...